# Chanching the default presistence mode of mapwithstatedstream from Memory only to other modes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have written spark streaming application using Kfka and mapwithsta functions. I have attched a snapshot of my application for the storage level[image]

As you see the Kafka stream is serilized in both memory and disk..but I cant find a way to change the default presistence of the mapwithste internal streams..this the pice of code I am using

```
val messages=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, (String,String)](ssc,
  kafkaParams,
  fromOffsets,
 (r:org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]) =>(r.topic(),r.value()))
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
....
val mapped1=message.map(x=>(x._2.hashCode().toString(),x)).mapWithState(stateSpec1)
```

In my applications sates can become huge so I need to presiste the internal sates in emeory and disk..I would apprecite any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

`mapWithState` is a distributed in-memory state store. It saves your state inside an internal structure called `OpenHashMapBasedStateMap`. What you're currently persisting is the `KafkaRDD` created by `KafkaUtils.createDStream`. If you're not iterating that same input twice, there's no need to persist it.

Remember that even if your internal state is huge, it should be evenly distributed inside your cluster. This means that you're not putting all your eggs in one basket, but spreading it throughout the cluster. If your state grows, you can always scale out your cluster with an additional node.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I am looking for a way to compact MapWithStaeRDD as the result of my mapwithState function. The states become large since by default it's presisting mode is Memory only based . I am using Spark 1.6.1. In my case keys are large and the timeout is somehow infinite..perhaps it is betterto use UpdateStaeBykey insteadas its internal state is Memory_Serlized..but curious to find a way to compact Mapwithstae RDD( even can't use Kyro since the sate classes such as OpenHashMapBasedStateMap are private in the package)..

Comment: Also I noticed that sometimes my mapwithsrateRDD become serialized (Serialized 1x Replicated) which  then take up less spaces.. but most of the time it is Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated..not sure about this!